.NET 8 OpenIDConnect fail when upgrading from .NET 6
I have a .NET Razor application that works fine connecting to OpenIDConnect via proxy in .NET 6. Once it is upgraded to use .NET 8, it fails. It will run in Visual Studio without the proxy. I have tried every option on the Microsoft learn page.
It gets to Microsoft and calls company authentication but does not pass that back to the application. So there is something different in how proxy calls need to be made.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UseProxy) && UseProxy.Equals("true"))
{
    builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            UseProxy = true,
            Proxy = new WebProxy()
            {
                Address = new Uri(configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").GetValue<string>("proxyserver"))
            }
        };
    });
}

I have tried adding the UseForwardedHeaders option and it is not working. The above code works fine in .NET 6 but not in .NET 8.
I followed this workaround found on GitHub and it does work. I am not sure what the implication is of adding the proxy as the DefaultProxy is though. Prior to adding this it was making it to MS login but was not returning all the headers from company login.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45688
